# Blank Result of ping command - Windows 10

Tags: windows, internet, cmd.exe, ping

When I try to ping some IP or whatever, always CMD shows me a blank screen.

[image: CMD Pic]

So what should I do?

All my Drivers and windows are updated

Edit 1: I tried creating a new local account and failure. also trying disable my anti virus and same result.

Edit 2: In my case, when i upgrade my windows whit ISO file downloaded, and install it, without loosing any data my ping command back to normal. But I can't figure it why this problem shows up !

Thanks to @harrymc for good idea.

Comment: ping your loopback adapter and see if you get a result  `ping 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Narzard Nope, still same and nothing showed up.

Comment: Create a new user profile, run the same command as that user, does the behavior still exhibit itself?  Edit your question instead of submitting comments to questions asked in the comments.

Comment: Also, what antivirus do you use? There are some reports of this issue with specific vendors.

Comment: @Ramhound i create new one and nothing changed.

Comment: @Narzard I use BitDefender, also disable it but still ping serult is empty

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you open Powershell and enter `ping 8.8.8.8` do you get different results?

Comment: @Narzard Sorry, but nope ):

Comment: I assume you are not using a AD domain user since you were able to create and access a local user profile?

Comment: Check the Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application Logs > Sort log by > Error and see if you have any related to the ping issue.

Comment: @Ramhound sure, i can create a local user account and how should i check my account have active domain ?

Comment: @Narzard no error for ping.

Comment: Do you have Internet on the computer? Can you give us more info about the computer and the local network and router?

Comment: Alternatively, testing some of your stack, do you get results if you perform `tracert 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, this is my personal computer and modem connect to it with cable. I'm using windows 10 latest build, I've D-link 2730-U. if you need any specific, tell me.

Comment: @Narzard This code also gives nothing, it says want to hop for 30 times but stack on first and nothing showed up.

Comment: Run tests: `chkdsk`, [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html), [DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html).

Comment: @harrymc no error found ):

Comment: The only operation which is not the re-installation of Windows that I can think of is [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). Take precautions such as good backups first, as this is exactly the same as doing a major Windows update.

Comment: @harrymc YES! i guess something changed in my registry and when I upgrade windows with ISO file, everything back to normal. Thanks so much

Comment: Is it fixed now?

Comment: @harrymc Yep :D

Comment: So this calls for an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only operation which is not the re-installation of Windows that I can think of is [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Take precautions such as good backups first, as this is exactly the same as doing a major Windows update.